# Disable third-party apps on Shopify

Tags: shopify

I wanted to know if is it possible to disable third-party app on Shopify when in development mode. I tried finding answers in Shopify website but I got nothing. Can you tell me if it's possible? Thanks.

Comment: Who controls that app? You? Who controls that development store? Please be more specific so I can be more useful.

Comment: @alexandresaiz, I have no control on the app but I am the one who develop the store now.

Comment: Is there a way to suspend an app without removing it

Comment: I don't think there is a way to temporarily disable them, I've been looking for this as well. One possible solution, depending on your situation, is to use Chrome's Request Blocking. If only a single js file is loaded to use the app, you could [Block the js/css request with Chrome Inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#block-requests).